# how to give descent sort without using any sort command parameter

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Now I want to do descend sort without using any sort command parameter.So i think out one way,let every value multiple -1,and the max will be min,the min will be max.And then because sort comand is sorted by the first value,if not added any comand parameters.So I print the format value ,let every value has the same bits.This ways will be used for map-reduce.
mapper code:

```
import sys
import re
for line in sys.stdin:
    adver_num=0
    line=line.strip()
    words=line.split('\t')
    adver_num= (-1)*(int(words[0]))
    print"%09.0f\t%s\t%s"%(adver_num,words[1],words[2])
```

and then cat a.log|python mapper.py|sort > b.log.
And the b.log,it seem the minus number still not work.

The last line in b.log are showed as below.It seem that sort command didn't consider the minuse .How can I fix it?

```
-00026844
-00027621
-00029789
-00029848
-00030789
-00032120
-00034452
-00034458
-00037064
-00038644
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)` function.
You can find the details here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 0):

`sort` with no options will sort lexically, so `-2` is before `-3` simply because they are treated as strings, not numbers.  Use `sort -n` to fix that, or read on.

If you have a ceiling value (the highest maximum value the first column can take) then you can subtract from that.  To avoid additional arithmetic down the pipeline, you can add this as a prefix and then strip it after the sort (see also [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)).

Let's say the maximum can never exceed 10,000,000.  Then you can stipulate that as the theoretical maximum, and do something like

```
import sys
import re
ceiling=10000000
for line in sys.stdin:
    line=line.strip()
    words=line.split('\t')
    sortkey=ceiling-int(words[0])
    print "%09.0f\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (sortkey, words[0],words[1],words[2])
```

Then you can strip off the first column after sorting.

```
python a.py <a.log | sort | cut -f2- >a.out
```

If you are satisfied with reading the entire data set into memory (like in @ViktorKerkez' answer), you trivially have the maximum available, and can use that as the ceiling value.  That has the distinct disadvantage that you cannot process a data set which will not fit into memory (and a data set which does not fit into physical memory will be extremely slow to handle, due to swapping).